# Print if only the latest date(2 to 8 column) backup has pattern "failed"

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Below is the requirement.

1. Ignore lines containing pattern "SET SNAP_ID" or "Shadow Copy Components:\" .
2. Ignore lines with column 2 till 8 is empty.
3. print lines containing pattern "Failed".
4. Print if only the latest date(2 to 8) backup has pattern "failed". (Ignore if "failed" in previous date and "successful" in concluding date.)
5. please attached html report and csv file.

Using bash script how can I achieve above conditions from linux server on csv file .

I have tried the following:

```
cat csv_report.csv | awk '!/SET SNAP_ID/' | awk '!/Shadow/'

cat csv_report.csv | awk -F'=' '!/^$/{arr[$1]=$2}END{for (x in arr) {print x"="arr[x]}}'

cat csv_report.csv | grep "Failed"
```

csv_report.csv is as below -

```
Client Name Friday 08/8 Saturday 08/9 Sunday 08/10 Monday 08/11 Tuesday 08/12 Wednesday 08/13 Thursday 08/14 Friday 08/15 elgar.ppp->E:\ Failed Full FS_Win_801_Thu_B Full_Backup 0B;
gershwin.ppp->D:\ Failed Full FS_Win_801_Thu_B Full_Backup 0B;
mozart.ppp->D:\ Successful Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Synthetic_Full 0B; Failed Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Full_Backup 0B;
nicklaus.ppp->C:\ Successful Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Synthetic_Full 0B; nicklaus.ppp->D:\ Successful Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Synthetic_Full 0B; Failed Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Full_Backup 0B; Failed Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Synthetic_Full 0B; samgdef00.ppp->C:\ Successful Full FS_Win_801_Thu_B Full_Backup 0B; Failed Full FS_Win_801_Thu_B Full_Backup 0B;
samgdef00.ppp->E:\ Failed Full FS_Win_801_Thu_B Full_Backup 0B;
samgdef06.ppp->C:\ Successful Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Synthetic_Full 0B; Failed Full FS_Win_801_Fri_B Synthetic_Full 0B;
```

Comment: Can you show us what "column 2 till 8 is empty" looks like? How many (space-separated) fields are left?

Comment: How are fields separated - commas, semi-colons, spaces, what? What does "please attached html report and csv file." mean? What if a line contains both `SET SNAP_ID` and `Failed` - ignore it or print it? Reduce your input to some small set (e.g. 10 lines of 10 SMALL fields each) that represents your problem so we don't have to read a ton of irrelevant information and show the expected output given that sample input.

Comment: It looks like they are **semi-colons** from the data provided. So I guess it is really a `.scsv` file.

Answer (score 0):

`awk -v FS=';' '{if(NF>2&&$0~/Failed/&&$0~!/SET SNAP_ID/&&$0~!/Shadow/)print $0}' file`

Comment: Posting code is all well and good, but doesn't make for a very good answer unless you are also willing to explain your code.

Comment: He already expressed the concepts utilized in the answer except for perhaps that FS is field separator and NF is number of fields, this answer fits the data he posted yet won't work in out of sequence semi-colon separated fields